# Is there any way to send EventBridge events to custom http endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-api-gateway, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to send event which comes to EventBridge to my service endpoint with event as payload, now my service is running on ec2 instance and part of a **specific VPC**, and is listening for http requests, my initial plan was to use API destination as the target of my rule, but when configuring the destination, i am being forced to provide https endpoint. This is a problem, my service is created to handle http calls not https

I am able to choose another target called API Gateway, now this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-gateway-target.html) here is not saying anything about https, is it possible to use this to make http calls to this service, if this is not the right way, is there any way to make http calls to my service using the event as payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in multiple ways,
one is to create a Lambda function which can be attached to the VPC where the ALB is running, and attach this Lambda as a target to rule target, in Lambda you can configure max concurrent executions and a dlq for events which cant get an execution chance(will not happen mostly if the volume is not too high)

second is to create public Rest APi which and a new VPC Link has to be configured for this, using this VPC Link requests can reach this ALB

One more option is to create SQS queue as target and service should have a consumer for this, but this means endpoints wont be used anymore

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: EventBridge Product Manager here.

Currently delivering events to private HTTP/S endpoints in VPC is only possible through workarounds e.g., using intermediary Lambda or SQS resources.

Feel free to reach out to your AWS account/support team so we can discuss this requirement further.